# Removing paths from .so files so that RPM check-buildroot succeeds

Tags: linux, pip, shared-libraries, rpmbuild

I am packaging some Python libraries as RPMs. Some of the libraries are only available as source distributions (no wheels).

In my RPM spec I do:

```
pip install --root=%{buildroot} --prefix=/x/y tornado
```

When `rpmbuild` finishes up it runs `check-buildroot`, and the build fails with errors like:

> Binary file /a/b/c/BUILDROOT/my-rpm-1.0.0-1.el7.x86_64/x/y/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/speedups.so matches

I see the `%{buildroot}` path listed if I run `strings tornado.so | grep BUILDROOT`.

How can I sanitize the `.so` files? Or more generally, how can I make `check-buildroot` pass?

Comment: Someone else had the same issue: https://github.com/kevinconway/rpmvenv/issues/48#issuecomment-284198086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to remove the paths from the SO files.

I determined that the paths were embedded debug information using this command:

```
readelf --debug-dump=line speedups.so | less
```

The `strip` command can remove debug information from SO files, so I added this to my RPM spec:

```
BuildRequires: binutils

set +e
find "%{buildroot}{%_prefix}/lib64/python2.7/site-packages" -type f -name "*.so" | while read so_file
do
    strip --strip-debug "$so_file"
done
set -e
```

Note: `strip` segfaults on some SO files, and it's not clear why. I disabled immediate exits with `set +e` so that the build ignores them.